# Issues with GridLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to create a 2x2 grid out of 4 buttons for a membership program I am developing.  The issue I'm having is that regardless of what I do, it just shows up as a 1x4 grid. Code is as follows.

```
    private void buildStartupPanel()
{
    startup = new JPanel();
    startup.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    addMember = new JButton ("Add a new member");
    removeMember = new JButton ("remove Member");
    reviewMember = new JButton ("Review a Member");
    reviewAll = new JButton ("Review All Members");
    startup.add(addMember);
    startup.add(removeMember);
    startup.add(reviewMember);
    startup.add(reviewAll);
    addMember.addActionListener(this);
    removeMember.addActionListener(this);
    reviewMember.addActionListener(this);
    reviewAll.addActionListener(this);
}
```

When I output the result, it shows the following

Add a new Member

Remove Member

Review A Member

Review all Members

Instead of

Add a new Member       Remove A Member

Review A Member        Review all Members

Also if anyone could help me put a space between each of the buttons that would be great!

Comment: This link will help with padding at least: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html See the second code segment.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 3rd & 4th `int` to the constructor for spacing.  Otherwise, seems to work just fine here:

[image: Startup Pane]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartupPanel {

    private JComponent getStartupPanel()
    {
        JPanel startup = new JPanel();
        startup.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,50,5));
        JButton addMember = new JButton("Add a new member");
        JButton removeMember = new JButton("remove Member");
        JButton reviewMember = new JButton("Review a Member");
        JButton reviewAll = new JButton("Review All Members");
        startup.add(addMember);
        startup.add(removeMember);
        startup.add(reviewMember);
        startup.add(reviewAll);

        return startup;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StartupPanel sp = new StartupPanel();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp.getStartupPanel());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: One critical difference: `JOptionPane` invokes `pack()`; OP's code may not.

Comment: @trashgod 1) Until we see an SSCCE, we cannot be sure what the OP's code does - it might call `pack()` immediately after adding the constructed panel.  2) I tried it quickly in a frame with set size but no pack.  Same 2x2 effect. -- Having said that, I cannot for the life of me figure why the OP is seeing a single column of 4 buttons.

Comment: You're right about an SSCCE; I was speculating that the apparent "1x4 grid" might reflect the (default) `FlowLayout` of `JPanel`.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the responses!! Come to find out it was my 2nd panel that I was adding to the code was misspelled (woops) and throwing everything off.  Guess that's the importance of posting a full SSCCE.  At least I learned how to do the spacing! thanks all!

Comment: Sorry for not accepting the answer before Andrew. I'm new to the application development world and even newer to StackOverflow.  I have accepted your answer. thank you for your help